# Add to each array element another element php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, sorting, foreach

I'm having one more problem in the logical realm.

I have an array containing ids:

$product_ids = ['1', '5', '3']; <- Example

Another string that I convert to an array separating it by commas, this to indicate the quantities of the products to be withdrawn. For example for product 1 I want 3 drives so I would need the array element to be "1,3".

$finalarray = ["1,3", "5,2", "3,10"];

Next I indicate the code that is executed in the controller (where is what I previously told):

```
public function ordenform(Request $request)
{

    $input = $request->all();

    $request->validate([
        'nombre' => 'required|string',
        'apellido' => 'required|string',
        'productos' => 'required',
        'cantidades' => 'required|string',
        'enviosino' => 'required|in:si,no',
    ]);

    // Quantity Array
    $cantidades = explode(',', $input['cantidades']);
    if (count($cantidades) != count($input['productos'])) {
        return back()->withErrors(['Las cantidades no corresponden a los productos agregados']);
    }

    $total = 0;
    $ganancia = 0;

    foreach ($input['productos'] as $producto) {
        $producto = Product::find((int) $producto);
        $total += $producto->value;
        $ganancia += $producto->ganancia;
        $producto->stock = (int) $producto->stock - 1;
        $producto->save();
    }

    if ($input['enviosino'] == 'si') {
        $total += (int) $input['envio'];
    }

    if ($input['envio'] == null) {
        $input['envio'] = 0;
    }

    // Products IDS Array
    $jsonproductos = json_encode($input['productos']);

    Order::create([
        'nombre' => $input['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $input['apellido'],
        'product_ids' => $finalprods,
        'value' => $total,
        'ganancia' => $ganancia,
        'envio' => $input['envio'],
    ]);

    $caja = Config::where('id', 1)->get()->first();
    $caja->dinerototal += $total;
    $caja->gananciatotal += $ganancia;
    $caja->save();

    return back()->with('success', 'Orden creada correctamente');
}
```

Finally, I need to pass as creation parameter the final array to the column products_ids (later I will modify the name).

Another option I thought of is passing objects to an array:

[{id: 1, quantity: 3}]

But I don't know how to get to create that object, I'm still kind of new hehe.

I hope I have explained myself well, English is not my native language. I'm sorry.

I am attentive to your comments !! Greetings.

PS: I am using Laravel

Answer (score 1):

To achieve `[{id: 1, quantity: 3}]` there will be several idea, but it seems to be an arrayList, so below is how you can create an arrayList in PHP. I have not tested the code, just written here, but should give you the idea to achieve this.

I am considering one is Order class.

```
 <?php
class Order {
        private $id;
        private $quantity;
    
        public function setId(int $id) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getId(){
            return $this->id;
        }
    
        public function setQuantity(int $quantity) {
            $this->quantity  = $quantity;
            return $this;
        }
    
        public function getQuantity(){
            return $this-> quantity;
        }
    
        public function toArray(){
           return [
               'id' => $this->getId(),
               'quantity' => $this->getQuantity()
           ];
        }
    }
?>
```

another is OrderList.

```
<?php
class OrderList {
       private $orderList;
    
       public function __construct(Order ...$orders) {
            $this->orderList = $orders;
       }
     
       public function toArray(){
          $arr = [];
          foreach ($this->orderList as $order) {
            $arr[] = $order->toArray();
          }
          return $arr;
       }
    }
?>
```

and then use like

```
$order1 = new Order();
$order1 = $order1->setId(1)->setQuantity(10);
$order2 = new Order();
$order2 = $order1->setId(2)->setQuantity(20);
    
$orderList = new OrderList($order1, $order2);
var_dump(json_encode($orderList->toArray()));
```

//Output

```
string(47) "[{"id":2,"quantity":20},{"id":2,"quantity":20}]"
```

You do not need json_encode, I have added it to print only.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, resolved ->

```
        $prodsfinal = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($cantidades); $i++) {
        $array = [
            'id' => json_decode($input['productos'][$i]),
            'cantidad' => (int) $cantidades[$i],
        ];
        array_push($prodsfinal, $array);
    }
```